# Using pipeline with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to define a quantizer to use with Pipeline/GridSearchCV in sklearn. When defining as below

```
class Quantizer(base.BaseEstimator, base.TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):

    def transform(X, y=None):
      some code
```

I'm getting something like

> method fit is missing

Am I missing something in the definition of the class?

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing the entire code, but it looks like you're missing the implementation for your 'fit' method. Do you have a method like that in 'some code'?

Comment: in my case fit wouldn't do anything. I am modifying values based on a static rule.

Comment: I'm not saying it has to do anything. As @elyase states, returning self is adequate. As long as there is some kind of definition for 'fit' available, which seems to be missing in your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are only transforming data in an intermediate state of your pipeline you don't need to implement a fit method, so you just return `self`:

```
class Quantizer(base.BaseEstimator, base.TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
      # some code 

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
      return self
```

Take a look [here](http://zacstewart.com/2014/08/05/pipelines-of-featureunions-of-pipelines.html) for more details.

Comment: it is saying that global name self is not defined. shouldn't it always be available in a class?

Comment: Check that `self` is the first argument of all methods in your class. You should paste your code in a gist in order to take a closer look.

Comment: I am missing 'self' in transform